# A 'distance' measure that involves 3 quantum states

Tags: quantum-information, distance, quantum-states

*The following question was asked by my friend Elie Wolfe.*

Given two quantum (or even classical) states $\rho, \sigma$, there are various measures that say how 'far' these two quantum states are, such as fidelity, trace distance, relative entropy, Renyi relative entropies etc. While most of these measures may not be a 'distance' in strict mathematical sense (for example, fidelity does not satisfy a triangle inequality), they all share a very nice property that they are monotonic under the action of a quantum map. More precisely, let $D(\rho,\sigma)$ be any of above measures (in case of fidelity, let $D(\rho,\sigma) = -\log (F(\rho,\sigma))$) and let $\mathcal{E}$ be a trace preserving quantum map. Then it holds that

$D(\mathcal{E}(\rho),\mathcal{E}(\sigma)) <= D(\rho,\sigma).$

The question is if there is any measure $D(\rho,\sigma,\tau)$ that is

1) defined for *three* quantum states $\rho,\sigma,\tau$,

2) is not merely a function of measures for two quantum states and

3) is monotonic under a quantum map: 
$D(\rho,\sigma,\tau) >= D(\mathcal{E}(\rho),\mathcal{E}(\sigma),\mathcal{E}(\tau)).$

An intuition behind this question (that my friend gave) is the following. Consider two unit vectors in Hilbert space. Trace distance between these vectors measures the `euclidean distance' between them. Then maybe the measure for three vectors corresponds to the 'area' enclosed by tips of the vector.

Comment: To start with, for qubits you could use the area spanned in the Bloch sphere.

Comment: Just some thoughts ... You could try to follow the theory of volumes in normed spaces (closely related to convex sets). But you have to be careful if there is no a triangle inequality. If you have a proper distance on the space where you have embedded your state space, then there are infinitely many ways of constructing notions of volume. One example would be the Hausdorff measure. These notions collapse to a canonical one if your distance originates from an inner product as the trace. Also these volumes share the properties that maps which do not increase distance does not increase volume.

Comment: Is there some *operational* intuition behind this?  For two states, these measures typically have some interpretation, like how well we can distinguish between the states or how likely we might mistake one for the other.  Then, the LOCC monotonicity is an obvious property.  Is there any similar intuition for asking for a three-state monotone?  With such an intuition, it might be easier to come up with such a monotone.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch  Do you know if the area spanned in Bloch sphere would satisfy monotonicity?

The motivation for this question comes from study of quantum nonlocality, in particular the recent paper : http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00213  , where fidelity plays the key role. We would like to see if a measure for three quantum states gives better dimension lower bounds. Apart from this, we do not have much intuition for this question.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich , Interesting! Could you provide some good references for your comment, where I can find the results that you have stated?

Comment: @anuraganshu My intuition of the action of a TPCP map on the Bloch sphere is that it is a rotation + a contraction, so it should shrink every geometric quantity.  But qubit channels have been exhaustively analyzed, so you should find this in the literature. But you seem to have an operational motivation; maybe it makes more sense to come up with a quantity which is useful in your context and then try to see if it is a monotone.

Comment: A good introduction is "Volumes on Normed and Finsler Spaces" by Alvarez Paiva & Thompson: http://library.msri.org/books/Book50/files/02AT.pdf; It requires some differential geometric background, though. The main idea is found in the first paragraphs of section 3. It could look like these ideas rely heavily on the notion of a vector space, but convex geometry and the geometry of normed spaces are in many ways related. But I don't know if this helps you,  the answer to your question could be that there are many. Maybe if you demand additional properties. Let me know if I shall elaborate this.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Can Bures distance work? I think it's well defined and widely used in quantum information theory.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Please forget about my last message since I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @anurag anshu Just a guess. If for 3 states A,B,C in the state space, and the distance between 2 states is a geodesic distance which satisfies the monotonic condition, then we can have the geodesics connecting AB,AC,BC.The 'area' of the triangle A,B,C can be defined by integrating the lengthes of geodesics between correspondent points on the geodesic AB,AC (for example by selecting equally separated points on AB,AC). Can this be a 'distance'? Though this is operational difficult to compute, but at least it seems to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: @X dong, what does 'correspondent point' mean in your example? So are not you computing area in usual way but defining a new notion of area?

Comment: @anurag anshu For me the definition of 'area' is similar to the normal area in Euclidean space. But the 'correspondent points' on AB,AC can be defined as distributed uniformly w.r.t. the geodesic distance along AB, AC. Of course, I doubt that this integration might not be finite for a 'bad' metric (for example in the work of Nielsen's geometric picture of quantum computation, where the curvature is believed to be almost negative).  I hope Bures metric can be used to define the geodesic distance.  The simplest idea, the sum of the distances AB,AC,BC as your 'distance' and it should work.

Comment: @anurag anshu I am not sure what do you mean by 'usual way to compute area'.  Can this be defined uniquely on Riemannian manifolds? I doubt we have different ways to define how to compute the area on Riemannian manifolds, and they will lead to different results. But we may choose one that might fulfill our requirement.